# Vagrant cannot find box on mac osx

Tags: macos, vagrant

I am trying to do something like:

```
vagrant init hashicorp/precise64
vagrant up
```

however, I am getting an error message when Vagrant tries to add the box 'hashicorp/precises64' --- I get the same error when I use the command

```
vagrant box add hashicorp/precise64
```

Here is the error:

```
The box 'hashicorp/precise64' could not be found or
could not be accessed in the remote catalog. If this is a private
box on HashiCorp's Atlas, please verify you're logged in via
`vagrant login`. Also, please double-check the name. The expanded
URL and error message are shown below:

URL: ["https://atlas.hashicorp.com/hashicorp/precise64"]
Error:
```

Does anyone know what is going wrong?

I am using Vagrant 1.8.7 on Mac OSX Yosemite 10.10.5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's an error in vagrant's version of curl for Mac OS X.
This error occurs even when the .box file is local.

To fix, just remove the offending file and it should default to the version of curl already installed on your system.

sudo rm /opt/vagrant/embedded/bin/curl

Comment: God bless you, kind soul.